# Can you trigger a command from another in telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram

Is it possible to force one command handler to run another in the same way as if the user did it him/herself, the example below is taken from the [repo](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/inlinekeyboard.py) over at github for ``python-telegram-bot```

The goal is to trigger the `/help` command  when the user chooses a any button from start

```
"""
Basic example for a bot that uses inline keyboards. For an in-depth explanation, check out
 https://git.io/JOmFw.
"""
import logging

from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, CallbackContext

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Sends a message with three inline buttons attached."""
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Option 1", callback_data='1'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Option 2", callback_data='2'),
        ],
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Option 3", callback_data='3')],
    ]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    update.message.reply_text('Please choose:', reply_markup=reply_markup)


def button(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Parses the CallbackQuery and updates the message text."""
    query = update.callback_query

    # CallbackQueries need to be answered, even if no notification to the user is needed
    # Some clients may have trouble otherwise. See https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text(text=f"Selected option: {query.data}")


def help_command(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Displays info on how to use the bot."""
    update.message.reply_text("Use /start to test this bot.")


def main() -> None:
    """Run the bot."""
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater("TOKEN")

    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('help', help_command))

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until the user presses Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I looked everywhere and search but no one seems to have a clear and straight forward explanation  if this is doable or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can directly call another function with the update and context from the function the program is in. To demonstrate I added a line in your *button* function. Also mind the rewrites necessary in *help_command* since it wants to reply to a message. There is no message when this function is called from *button*:

```
def button(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Parses the CallbackQuery and updates the message text."""
    query = update.callback_query

    # CallbackQueries need to be answered, even if no notification to the user is needed
    # Some clients may have trouble otherwise. See https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text(text=f"Selected option: {query.data}")

    help_command(update, context)


def help_command(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Displays info on how to use the bot."""
    # update.message.reply_text("Use /start to test this bot.")
    context.bot.send_message(update.effective_user.id, "Use /start to test this bot.")
```

If for some reason you'd insist on using the *reply_text* function, you could rewrite *help_command* like this:

```
def help_command(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Displays info on how to use the bot."""
    if hasattr(update.message, "reply_text"):
        update.message.reply_text("Use /start to test this bot.")
    else:
        context.bot.send_message(update.effective_user.id, "Use /start to test this bot.")
```

Hope this helps.